# How to change the header color of the MUI accordion to grey?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material-UI for React. I have a really simple question about the MUI accordions. I have the following piece of code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Accordion from "@material-ui/core/Accordion";
import MuiAccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
  }
}));

const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
})(MuiAccordionSummary);

export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion
        defaultExpanded={true}
      >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion
        defaultExpanded={true}
      >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to change the color of the header to grey. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, just change the background-color of `AccordionSummary`:

**V5**

```
<AccordionSummary
  sx={{
    backgroundColor: "gray"
  }}
>
```

**V4**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  summary: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  }
);
```

```
<AccordionSummary
  className={classes.summary}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Sorry for the really basic question, `V4` and `V5` are version 4/5 of what?

Comment: @vesii version 4/5 of Material-UI. There are many breaking changes in MUI v5, including how you style the components, so I include both versions just in case.

Comment: Well, I'm using 5.0.2 (checked the package.json file and saw `"@mui/material": "^5.0.2",`). Tried your first solution but it didn't add the colors. Do you know why?

Comment: @vesii It's because you're importing from `@material-ui/core` instead of `@mui/material` and `@material-ui/core/styles` instead of `@mui/material/styles`. In v4, it's called material-ui, in v5 they changes the brand name to mui and the package name to `@mui/...`